# how to create a png image

Tags: php, javascript, html, pdf, png

hi guys how to create a png image for inserting in pdf file by using html and php script

can anybody have ideas???give me some example

thanks jessy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Image Processing and Generation](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php) section of the manual

Answer (score 0):

phpthumb is a popular choice

http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/